# php Password verify for override feature returns false

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, passwords

I am trying to create an override feature where users type in existing login credentials, verify that a result row is returned matching those credentials, and then verifying that the user has the override role assigned to them. If both MySQL statements return true, I want to run the final query to delete a row from the coded table.

With my current code, the program passes the first if statement and runs the second SELECT statement. Then, it appears to run the second if to moved to the third SELECT statement. However, on the third if statement, the DELETE statement isn't successful.

I think I have a few issues:

- I don't know if I'm properly comparing the passwords.
- Could the problem be caused by the nested if statements?
- Is my problem 'if ($result1) {...}' (assuming that `result1` will return true as long as the SELECT statement successfully ran with 0 results returned)?

Either way, I'm not entirely sure of the best way to fix the(se) issue(s).

NOTE:: Through testing, I have confirmed that:

- My variables are successfully $_POSTing and of the correct datatypes.
- With just the first if/else statement, the alerted response was always a "success" result, even with incorrect credentials entered.

All help is appreciated!!

MY CODE:

PHP:

```
<?php

include('[db connection page]');

if ((isset($_POST['overrideUsername'])) and (isset($_POST['overridePassword'])) and (isset($_POST['overrideUniqueID']))) {

    $overrideUsername = $_POST['overrideUsername'];
    $overridePassword = $_POST['overridePassword'];
    $overrideUniqueID = $_POST['overrideUniqueID'];




    //connect  to the database 
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if(mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        printf('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $conn->select_db($dbname);

    if(! $conn->select_db($dbname) ) {
        echo 'Could not select database. '.'<BR>';
    }

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (users.login = \"".mysqli_real_escape_string($overrideUsername)."\") AND (users.password = ENCODE(\"".mysqli_real_escape_string(overridePassword)."\",\"".mysqli_real_escape_string(ENCRYPTION_SEED)."\"))";

    $result1 = $conn->query($sql1); 

    if ($result1) {

        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN rolestousers ON (users.id=rolestousers.userid) WHERE (users.login = \"".mysqli_real_escape_string($overrideUsername)."\") AND (users.password =ENCODE(\"".mysqli_real_escape_string(overridePassword)."\",\"".mysqli_real_escape_string(ENCRYPTION_SEED)."\")) AND (rolestousers.roleid = '154')";

        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);      

        if ($result2) {

            $sql3 = "DELETE * FROM locator_time_track_out WHERE locator_time_track_out.uniqueid = '.$overrideUniqueID'";

            $result3 = $conn->query($sql3); 


            if ($result3) {

                echo 'Override Successful! Please scan the unit again to close it out.';

            } else {

                echo 'Could Not Delete Record from the Table.';

            }//End $sql3 num_rows if.

        } else {

            echo 'User does not have override permission. Please contact the IT Department.';

        }//End $sql2 num_rows if.

    } else {

        echo 'Your login information is incorrect. Please try again. If the issue persists, contact the IT Department.';

    }//End $sql1 num_romws if.

 //Free the result variable. 
   $result1->free();
   $result2->free();
   $result3->free();


 //Close the Database connection.
   $conn->close();


}//End If statement
```

UPDATE:

This is the code file I was originally using for the override feature. However, it of course fails for an incorrect password...

```
 include('[db connection file name');

 if ((isset($_POST['overrideUsername'])) and (isset($_POST['overridePassword'])) and (isset($_POST['overrideUniqueID']))) {

    $overrideUsername = $_POST['overrideUsername'];
    $overridePassword = $_POST['overridePassword'];
    $overrideUniqueID = $_POST['overrideUniqueID'];

    //connect  to the database 
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if(mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        printf('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $conn->select_db($dbname);

    if(! $conn->select_db($dbname) ) {
        echo 'Could not select database. '.'<BR>';
    }

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (users.login = ?) AND (users.password = ?)";

    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql1);
    $stmt1->bind_param('ss', $overrideUsername, $overridePassword);
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->store_result();     

    if ($stmt1->num_rows == 1) {

        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN rolestousers ON (users.id=rolestousers.userid) WHERE (users.login = ?) AND (users.password = ?) AND (rolestousers.roleid = '154')";

        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
        $stmt2->bind_param('ss', $overrideUsername, $overridePassword);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $stmt2->store_result();     

        if ($stmt2->num_rows == 1) {

            $sql3 = "DELETE * FROM locator_time_track_out WHERE locator_time_track_out.uniqueid = ?";

            $stmt3 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
            $stmt3->bind_param('s', $overrideUniqueID);
            $stmt3->execute();
            $stmt3->store_result();     

            if ($stmt3->num_rows == 1) {

                echo 'Override Successful! Please scan the unit again to close it out.';

            } else {

                echo 'Could Not Delete Record from the Table.';

            }//End $sql3 num_rows if.

        } else {

            echo 'User does not have override permission. Please contact the IT Department at ext. 0102.';

        }//End $sql2 num_rows if.

    } else {

        echo 'Your login information is incorrect. Please try again. If the issue persists, contact the IT Department at ext. 0102.';

    }//End $sql1 num_romws if.


//Free the result variable. 
  $stmt1->free();
  $stmt2->free();
  $stmt3->free();



//Close the Database connection.
 $conn->close();


}//End If statement
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but just to let you know, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Try reading up on prepared statements to solve that issue.

Comment: Yes, I want to use prepared statements but I feel I'm running into issues trying to determine the way the original programmer encrypted the passwords in the db...

Comment: You presume they did, but it doesn't look like that happened, which is super bad. This is using a static encryption key, which is basically worthless. Everything about this is wrong. You really should decrypt all those passwords and properly hash them using [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) before your site is compromised.

Comment: So is there anything you would suggest for getting the application to work in the mean time while a security update is planned to address the password issue?

Comment: The first thing to do is use prepared statements with placeholder values to clean all of this junk up. The second thing is to stop creating useless variables like `$sql1` and instead prepare the query directly: `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT...")` to eliminate clutter. It's also not clear why there's a login query, then another query virtually identical with one additional clause. That second one shouldn't be necessary. Fetch the user information, then compare role values.

Comment: The best thing you can do to this code is throw gasoline on it and burn it to the ground, this is a ticking time-bomb. Remember most modern [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) have some kind of support for this built-in that's tested and proven to be secure. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) has a very complete [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) that should be at least evaluated. Steer towards using community-supported code, not home-rolled confusion like this.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.